# jQuery animate() show the percent of the animation progress

Tags: jquery-animate, progress

With that following snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/sylouuu/V7a3Y/2/
I would like to show the % progress in #log of the animation from 0% to 100%, the 100% is easy with the callback...

Is it possible to do that?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery animate progress callback was introduced in 1.8:

```
$('#a').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    width: 400,
    percent: 100
}, {
    progress: function(animation, progress, msRemaining) {
        $('#log').html(100 * progress + "%");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do that by using the step function

```
 $('myelementid').animate({
   opacity: 1,
   height: 100,
   percent: 100
 },
 {
   step: function(now, fx) {
      //not sure if this is 100% percent accurate 
      //but at least you have a value at every step of the animation
      console.log( this.percent );          
   },
   complete: function(){
       //do not forget to reset percent at the end of the animaton
       //so on the next animation it can be calculated from starting value of 0 again
       this.percent = 0;
   }
 });
```

Hope this helps.